# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() not working with swift in xcode 6 Beta2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, location-services

I'm trying to implement a more efficient background handling of my location dependent application and also learn some Swift while doing so.

I noticed (the hard way) that I couldn't get locations to work at all in the first Beta but switching to Beta2 of xcode solved that part.

In the setup of my location handling I initiate a LocationManager with code like this (I want to be able to switch to high resolution and even start in high mode):

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
```

And then handle switching with code like:

```
if (highResolutionSwitch.on) {
  println("Switching to high resolution");
  locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges();
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
} else {
  println("Switching to low resolution");
  locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation();
  locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges();
}
```

When in "high"-mode I receive locations in my `didUpdateLocations()` method but NEVER anything in "low"-mode.
Is it the beta nature of the xcode/swift-environment or am I missing something?

Comment: are you testing on the simulator or a real device?

Comment: I'm testing on both. It now works (se my own response)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem found!

The problem was that the call to `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` was not enough. This doesn't enable significant location changes.
Changing that line to `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` made at least the simulator to give me one location (although no new location when I changed the position).

I will redeploy my app and see if it works IRL.

*I also needed to reinstall the app on the simulator so that the "allow" question was given again.*

Comment: Is it too early before my morning coffee, or are the old call and the new call identical in your answer?

Comment: @Matt You are 100% correct, I will change that to the function *requestAlwaysAuthorization()*